# Google Chrome Crashes

Tags: google-chrome, crash, google-chrome-extensions

I was happily trolling the internet tonight when Google Chrome decided to perform some update function, which is fine. However upon attempting to launch Chrome I get errors stating it was unable to display the webpage. This is the same for all internal pages such as: `chrome://bookmarks/` or `/settings`.

I also get the initial error/popup stating my extensions and add-ons fail to launch. The same errors occur in incognito mode (yes, I allowed my extensions to work in Incognito mode too). Short of uninstalling and reinstalling Google, are there any other options (such as Google Launch options) I can test?

The only reason I do not want to uninstall is all user data is setup to use a different passphrase than my Google account passcode, and I am not entirely sure how to import all this if I uninstall. (Unless there will be no issues restoring this, not sure if the uninstall process removes all the local files) and also, I have edited many of the Google Chrome flags, which I believe are unique per install (correct me if I am wrong).

**Update 1 - Testing**

Tested the following [arguments](http://www.ericdlarson.com/misc/chrome_command_line_flags.html):

`-testshell-startup-dialog`

`--enable-logging --log-level 0`

`--safe-plugins`

However these proved to be of no help to me. All plugins seemed to launch and crash simultaneously.

**Update 2 - Information on Hardware/Software**

**OS Version**: Windows 10 Pro x64

**Chrome Version**: Latest version as of 7:31 pm - 16/09/2016

Comment: My answer below assumes that you are referring to your local PC account, not your Google account when you said, "The only reason I do not want to uninstall is all user data is setup to use a different passphrase than my Google account passcode."   Correct?  If so, using these two accounts should have no effect and no conflict since they never interact.

Comment: Under Google Chrome options for syncing data, I elected to use a different passphrase for the data rather than relying on the Google Chrome passcode.

Comment: It appears that the only thing that would not be synced, would be history:  https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1181035?visit_id=1-636096321346717271-1496062440&p=settings_encryption&rd=1  Even then, back up the profile information FOLDERS using Explorer and you should be able to restore these folder[s] to either this PC or another PC.  I still don't see what you'd be missing, other than your volatile replaceable cache.

Comment: I'm creating migration tools for Firefox now for public use.  But I never saw the need to even bother with Chrome.  I'd  like to hear from anyone else or you, Michael, if there's a need for a migration or backup tool for Chrome when you actually log into the browser itself, locally.

Comment: Well, personally I am not entirely sure the feasibility of what exactly could be backed up. It would be quite useful, especially in a corporate environment to utilize such a tool: users may utilize Chrome web-marks/passcodes etc. without actually logging into a Google account.

Comment: I will try it on some test PCs, create a little history, a few plugins, and then copy all the required files to the new PC.  I know it works very well in Firefox, Skype, etc.  And, I agree, most user probably don't log into their browsers automatically if they don't know why they would do so, or aren't prompted by Google to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you logged in with a Google account in the browser itself, you should be able to just completely uninstall and then reinstall Chrome.  As soon as you log into the new install, Google will automatically reinstall ALL of the plugins you had, and reinstall almost all the settings that you had for your user account.

To TEST this so you can see exactly how this works, install Chrome using a separate PC that you will always have access to and don't mind your files being accessed on.  Even if Chrome is already installed and someone else in you family is using it for their account, just click on the personality at the extreme top right of a Chrome screen, to the left of the - X.  Now log into Chrome itself with your Google account.

Most all settings and preferences and all user data will now be on this new PC installation.  Some settings that are directly related to your PC itself and NOT your account will not be transferred, but most settings will be.  Some settings within plugins will also need to be set up on the new PC or now Chrome installation.